# Solve $\lim\limits_{h\to0} \frac{e^{2h^2}-1}{h^2}$

Tags: limits

I am trying to solve a simple derivative and have gotten it to the following form:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{2h^2}-1}{h^2}$$

Somehow the $\dfrac{e^x-1}x$ formula should be able to be used there, but I can't get it to the right form.

Comment: Divide and multiply by 2, then put the division into the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'Hopital yields

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{2h^2}-1}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{4he^{2h^2}}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0} 2e^{2h^2}=2$$

---

Or

\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{2h^2}-1}{h^2}&=\lim_{2h^2\to0} \frac{e^{2h^2}-1}{h^2}\\
&=\lim_{w\to0} \frac{e^w-1}{\tfrac12w}\\
&=\lim_{w\to0} 2\frac{e^w-1}{w}\\
&=2\lim_{w\to0} \frac{e^w-1}{w}\\
&=2\cdot1\\
&=2
\end{align}

Comment: Good answer, but It was supposed to be solved algebraically.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=2h^2$, so as $h\to0\implies x\to0$.

$$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^{2h^2}-1}{h^2}=2\cdot \lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^{2h^2}-1}{2h^2}=2\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}=2\times1=2$$

Answer (score 0):

If $h$ tends to $0$, $2h^2$ also tends to $0$. So

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{2h^2}-1}{2h^2}=1$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{2h^2}-1}{h^2}=\lim_{h^2\to0}2\left(\frac{e^{2h^2}-1}{2h^2}\right)=2$$